# How to get current view HTML source and pass it JSF ManagedBean as String

Tags: html, jsf-2, parameters

I want to get current view HTML source and pass it to JSF managed bean as a parameter. Is there anyway in JSF I can do this?

Comment: I wanted to geneate a pdf document on fly using Itext+flying saucer for I need the HTML of my page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in JSF as it doesn't run in the webbrowser at all.

Your best bet is using JavaScript. The below example sets a hidden input value with the HTML source code when the submit button is clicked:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="source" value="#{bean.source}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" 
        onclick="document.getElementById('form:source').value=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML"
    />
</h:form>
```

In the action method, it's in the particular example then just available by the `source` property.

Comment: Awesome It's working perfectly fine.Thanks Balu....But I tried same with Jquery by getting HTML using .html() of the entire div but not able to pass to backend.

Comment: not always works. I implemented this example in my application, but when outerHTML is very large something goes wrong. On click I haven't the managed bean called, but only a page refresh. Maybe inputHidden can't contains this large value ? (outerHTML number char is : 1954000)

Comment: Not a JSF problem but a serverconfig problem. Most servers have a default limit of 2GB on POST body size. Consult server documentation how to adjust it.

Comment: but never reach 2GB, is impossible, is only text . Server is Tomcat 9. Maybe 2MB ? where I can change this value ?

Comment: Ok thank you. Changed server.xml , I've set maxPostSize="6291456" in Connector tag. Now works!