# How access to content of dynamic page in JSF?

Tags: java, xml, jsf, jsf-2, sigma.js

I have a xhtml file that i initialized it with ui:repeat tag in realtime.all tags of this page placed under ui:fragment tag.

```
<edges>
     <ui:repeat value="#{graphInfoBean.edges}" var="edge" varStatus="indexVar">
        <edge id="#{indexVar.index}" source="#{edge.source}" target="#{edge.target}"
              weight="#{edge.weight}">
            <attvalues>
                <attvalue for="weight" value="#{edge.weight}"></attvalue>
            </attvalues>
        </edge>
     </ui:repeat>
```

When i access to this page and save it as xml in realtime, the tags in xml file saved are empty while it is initialized and everything is working properly.

```
<edges>
</edges>
```

How can i access to content of this xhtml file and save it on disk?

---

think that we have 2 page (A&B) so we want to download the page B (this page initialized dynamically by ManagedBean)through page A

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I am confused. So you do see content on the screen for those edge tags, but when you save the page source there is nothing there? If so - are those edges rendered as part of an ajax request?

Comment: I used the graph.xhtml as templating file for drawing graph in sigmajs library.its working properly but when i want to save  graph.xhtml, the content of tags are empty.

Comment: are you using `parseGexf(url)` to load gexf file or edges are in the same page?

Comment: thanks @ Michele Mariotti , yes i use `parseGexf( graph.xhtml)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function process(){
     url = "text.html"
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("GET", url, true);
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        alert(xhr.responseText)
        }
     }

     xhr.send();
   }
```

Sorry i cant post comments, maybe you can use this.

take a look at this thread: [get full html source code of page through ajax request through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847951/get-full-html-source-code-of-page-through-ajax-request-through-javascript)

Comment: thank you @xild ,i solved it like that , but i am searching for `jsf` solution

Comment: Hmm, JSF doesnt run in web browser, so this is impossible.

Client side x Server Side.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920594/how-to-get-current-view-html-source-and-pass-it-jsf-mangedbean-as-string

BaluSC post a elegant solution years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920594/how-to-get-current-view-html-source-and-pass-it-jsf-mangedbean-as-string